# How to debug if/elseif in Apache httpd.conf?

Tags: apache, if-statement, httpd.conf

Running Apache 2.4.38 on Windows 2012. I have the following config in my httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#.*smartbank.*#">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "https://bank.test.mycorp.no"
    Header set Vary: Origin
</If>
<ElseIf "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#.*startside.*#">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "https://testserver1.mycorp.no"
    Header set Vary: Origin
</ElseIf>
<ElseIf "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'localhost:8080'">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://localhost:8080"
    Header set Vary: Origin
</ElseIf>
```

For some reason the first elseif won't kick in. Is it any in any way possible to debug such statements, such as create log statements before, in and after the if else?

Comment: Try activating the debug Loglevel as a start: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel

Comment: No, I have not been able to see anything in the logs related to the if-statements, even if loglevel is trace8...

LogLevel info headers:trace8